# Refused to display ‘domain name displayed here’ in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: web, iframe, jboss, cross-domain, x-frame-options

We have a web application deployed in Jboss 7.2 Server. In some other domain we are trying to load and show our application URL inside Iframe. We are getting the error in browser console log Refused to display ‘domain name displayed here’ in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. Below are the things I tried doing but still facing the same issue. Please help me out if you know the solution for this problem.

•  Removed SAMEORIGIN configuration entry from JBoss Standalone.xml `<response-header name="x-frame-options" header-name="X-Frame-Options" header-value="SAMEORIGIN"/>`

•  Set HTTPServlet response object Access control header to allow all domains  `response.setHeader("access-control-allow-origin", "*");`

• Set HTTPServlet response object Set-Cookie attribute as None `response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", String.format("%s; %s", header, "SameSite=None"));`

Below is my Jboss Standalone configuration

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:11.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="*"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration changes you did on Wildfly look all good to allow it.
Are you sure that in response you are still getting "X-Frame-Options" as a header?
If not, it seems blocked on the browser. See this: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/09/disable-same-origin-policy/

PS: same-origin policy is enforced for security reasons. Keep a thought on that, while you take a decision.